# How to make portable distribution of application that uses cuda

Tags: cuda, cudafy.net

Is anyone know simple way to make all inclusive distribution of application that uses cuda with Cudafy.net wrapper?

I know that I have to install Toolkit and C++ compiler, but I would prefer to find more easier way to deploy to target machine.

Comment: Do you mean for development or deployment? Since you mentioned compiler and toolkit, sounds like you mean development environment setup. For that, you need to follow CUDA documentation: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-quick-start-guide/index.html#introduction

Comment: @void_ptr I ment deployment setup

Comment: For deployment, all you need is having a driver installed, of a version sufficiently high to support runtime that you are using.

Comment: @void_ptr, I use cudafy.net wrapper It throws exception when cl.exe not found.

Comment: @gabba: so your question is how to make a portable cudafy.net distribution. That is a different question.

Comment: @void_ptr: Unless you restrict yourself to the driver API or statically link your application, you will also need to distribute the runtime library the code is built against and any other CUDA libraries that rely on the runtime library (CUBLAS, CUFFT, etc)